# Versioning lots of data in real-time

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, versioning, bigdata

I'm looking for input on how to best approach data versioning for an application I'm working on.

**Summary**

I have row based data that changes multiple times a second. Some of the data is static, some highly variable, some in-between. I want to store all the deltas so I can go back to any point in time and capture the values.
Each state is equally important. I want to be able to search for and evaluate states, e.g. "Give me all the times X had value Y".

**Analogy: Car**

I'm going to explain my problem using a car as an analogy:

- I want to save every possible attribute of the car ( = lots of data )
- The car can be static ( = few updates ), or moving ( = many updates )
- The car might get a repaint ( = some values may seem static but they are not )
- I don't care where the car is going or coming from ( = all states equally important )
- I want to check where it stops ( = asking for states by attribute )
- I want to calculate distance driven between states ( = asking and comparing states )
- If someone steals the car, I want to know it right away ( = lots of updates in real-time )

We are talking about a gig of data per car, and tons of different cars.
I would also like to compare cars to one another at a later pointer ( e.g. do cars that are pink get stolen less? ), so more cars = more data.

**Picture Time**

I draw a quick diagram to visualize the updates: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kVYg.png). I will embed it once I get 10 rep.

**Questions**

Whats the best way to save my data? I'm thinking of some kind of sparse database solution with low overhead for duplicate values.
I'm open for any database engines or solutions.

Comment: Although this *is* a rather broad and potentially opinionated question, I would like to see it remain open.  The scope of the design problem is defined well, and I believe that viable answers will be of use to future SO members.  The Internet of Things will have many applications of this paradigm, and I believe that we already see the technology being accessible in the maker community.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store arriving facts is *completely*.  You only get one first look at the data, and the faster they're arriving the more important it is to secure them quickly and unmunged.

Wall Street has been doing this kind of thing for the better part of half a century.  Keep the slow-moving stuff -- names, addresses -- in one table, and the ephemeral stuff -- usually prices -- in another.  Don't worry too much about the "duplication"; apply the KISS principle first.  In managing deltas, it's very easy to foul things up, and easier still to swamp your "savings" with delta-bookkeeping overhead.  Plus, if you keep everything in neat rows, any SQL DBMS will answer point-in-time queries with a high degree of confidence.